# How to remove identical items from List<string>?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a List in which I select users from db each time a sql query runs with certain value and selects one user in the time thus I cannot limit identical users in sql.

I have list with:

```
list[0] = "jerry"
list[1] = "tom"
list[2] = "jerry"
```

I want any (first or last doesn't matter in my case) to be removed from the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LINQ can solve this:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "Tom", "Jerry", "Tom" };
IQueryable<string> distinctItems = names.Distinct();
```

If you want a list type, simply call ToList():

```
distinctItems.ToList();
```

Here's an example from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716801.aspx).

EDIT: Non-LINQ Example (using Contains() from the [List class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)):

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "Tom", "Jerry", "Tom" };
List<string> distinctNames = new List<string>();
foreach (var name in names)
{
    if (!distinctNames.Contains(name))
    {
        distinctNames.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without LINQ? Use traditional search and remove method.

Comment: See @lee's answer that uses a HashSet instead of LINQ.

Comment: @Fara, i've seen and it is indeed best and most creative answer but @Secret Agent Man answer fits my need more as i haven't provided all the info in my question.

Answer (score 22):

```
IEnumerable<string> uniqueUsers = list.Distinct();
```

You can also use a HashSet:

```
HashSet<string> uniqueUsers = new HashSet<string>(list);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Distinct() LINQ extension.

```
var list = new List<string> { "Tom", "Jerry", "Tom" };

var uniqueList = list.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx), as suggested in the other answers, will leave your original list intact and return a separate `IEnumerable<>` sequence containing the distinct items from your list.

An alternative would be to remove duplicates from your original list directly, using [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
var temp = new HashSet<string>();
yourList.RemoveAll(x => !temp.Add(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `list.distinct();`